# Xcode 10.1 profiling shaders this may take a while (forever???)

Tags: profiling, gpu, xcode10.1

I'm debugging an iOS/Metal app. When pressing the GPU capture frame button (the little camera) Xcode says: "Profiling shaders. This may take a while...", but is taking forever! 
Is that normal? How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]]

Comment: Since you are writing a custom filter I guess you already have found sucess with what I am stuck at. I am trying to apply a simple vignette filter to a live camera feed using metal. The results are pretty slow and laggy, please check this if you can tell me what is missing:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898780/1364053

Answer (score 0):

Set your project's "iOS Deployment Target" to a higher version.
It is still going to take a while, though, so be patient :)